# Is it possible to create a spring JPA DTO projection from a sub class of a full JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

Given a basic JPA entity:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I need to create a spring JPA DTO projection like the follwing:

```
class PersonProjection {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    String projectionProperty;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The `projectionProperty` is not something that could be handled via @Formula or standard jpa relationship, hence the use of a Projection.

Given that the projection has much in common with the entity, is it possible to use inheritance e.g.:

```
class PersonProjection extends Person {
   String projectionProperty;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Currently when trying to do this and calling the spring JPA repo method, I get an `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: PersonProjection` exception. I assume because spring doesn't realize that I am attempting to use a projection and instead wants to retrieve an entity, due to @Entity being on the parent class.

Is there a way I can indicate that although PersonProjection extends an entity, it is *not* an entity for the purposes of my specific repository method? Perhaps by excluding the subclass from JPA, or annotating the spring repo method?

Edit: Using projection interfaces (as I understand them) isn't a complete solution for my use case because downstream code needs the results to be Person entity instances, so the query results would have to be re-mapped manually into PersonProjection instances -  which is what Im trying to avoid to begin with.